# iPhone keyboard shrinks modal size for web application

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, input

I have a site that has a modal on it. When a div is clicked, the modal pops up. There is an input in the modal. When viewing the site on a mobile device, I have an issue where I when the input is clicked, the iPhone keyboard pops up. The modal appears to stay the same size, but if I then close the iPhone keyboard, the modal is shrunken to the screen size minus the keyboard size.

Comment: Are you using fixed position and/or bootstrap? If so look [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9023) and [here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/bootstrap-3-modals-and-the-ios-virtual-keyboard/).

Comment: Using fixed position...I'm checking out if changing it to absolute works...fingers crossed

Comment: @IMI right now the absolute seems to work, except that when I drag up on the overlay it exposes everything below

Comment: Can you provide a code sample that recreates your new problem?

Comment: @IMI actually the same thing as before happens whether it's`position fixed`  or `position absolute`

Comment: Are you able to provide a code sample that recreates the problem?

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a bug with iOS and the rendering of `position:fixed;` elements [when using the virtual keyboards](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-fixed-position-keyboards).

You should try changing your modal to use `position:absolute;` and see if that corrects the issue.

You can also try the [User Agent Sniffing method here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/bootstrap-3-modals-and-the-ios-virtual-keyboard/).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say without seeing any code, but perhaps you need to add the [viewport meta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) tag?

If you have not already done so, try this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```